# How to store value returned by nproc in linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cpu

I'm trying to store the number of CPUs in a variable for a linux bash shell.
I know nproc returns the number of CPUs however I can't seem to store the value returned in a variable.

I'm sure it's a simple solution so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use nested call to **nproc**:

```
$ NPROC=$(nproc)
echo $NPROC
1
```